# Spark Java Accumulator not incrementing

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

Just started with baby steps in Spark-Java. Below is a word count program that includes a stop word list that would skip words that are in the list. I have 2 accumulators to count the skipped words and unskipped words.

However, the `Sysout` at the end of program **always gives both accumulator values to be 0**.

Please point out where I am going wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Third App - Word Count WITH BroadCast and Accumulator");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> fileRDD = jsc.textFile("hello.txt");
        JavaRDD<String> words = fileRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {

            public Iterable<String> call(String aLine) throws Exception {
                return Arrays.asList(aLine.split(" "));
            }
        });

        String[] stopWordArray = getStopWordArray();

         final Accumulator<Integer> skipAccumulator = jsc.accumulator(0);
         final Accumulator<Integer> unSkipAccumulator = jsc.accumulator(0);

        final Broadcast<String[]> stopWordBroadCast = jsc.broadcast(stopWordArray);

        JavaRDD<String> filteredWords = words.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            public Boolean call(String inString) throws Exception {
                boolean filterCondition = !Arrays.asList(stopWordBroadCast.getValue()).contains(inString);
                if(!filterCondition){
                    System.out.println("Filtered a stop word ");
                    skipAccumulator.add(1);
                }else{
                    unSkipAccumulator.add(1);
                }
                return filterCondition;

            }
        });

        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$Filtered Count "+skipAccumulator.value());
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ UN Filtered Count "+unSkipAccumulator.value());

        /* rest of code - works fine */
        jsc.stop();
        jsc.close();
        }
```

I am making a runnable jar and submit the job on Hortonworks Sandbox 2.4 using

```
spark-submit jarname
```

**------------EDIT----------------**

REST of the code that goes in the commented portion

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> wordOccurrence = filteredWords.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String inWord) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(inWord, 1);
            }
        });

        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> summed = wordOccurrence.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

            public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) throws Exception {
                return a+b;
            }
        });

        summed.saveAsTextFile("hello-out");
```

Comment: Both the accumulators are 0 and since there are 5 occurrence of the stop words, the text Filtered a stop word prints 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed posting the important part `/* rest of code - works fine */`. I can just about guarantee that you are calling some action in that rest of code. Which triggers the DAG to execute the code with the accumulator. Try adding a `filteredWords.collect` before the println and you should see the output. Remember that Spark is lazy on transformations, and only executes on actions.

Comment: Edited the question. :)

Comment: Right Answer - Spark is lazy on transformations, and only executes on actions
I forcefully executed a first() to get it working.